# mysql_num_rows result order

Tags: php, mysql-num-rows

This is a question regarding the mysql_num_rows command. Basically what I want to ask if it's possible to sum the results up and order them in a descending order.

```
 $fetchrank = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM leden WHERE level = 6 OR level = 106");
 while ($getrank = mysql_fetch_array($fetchrank, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $getranked = mysql_query("SELECT nieuws_id FROM nieuws_berichten WHERE member_id='".$getrank['member_id']."'");
    $critical = mysql_num_rows($getranked);
    $posts = $critical;

    echo"".stripslashes(substr($getrank['gebruikersnaam'],0,25))." has ".$posts." posts!";
}

echo"</div>";
```

}

This actually shows it what I want, but I want it to order the num_rows results now, from highest to lowest. Is that possible through an array? so I can use a PHP command or is there another way?

I am aware that mysql_num_rows is outdated, however at the moment I'll be working with this old framework and perhaps in the near future we'll be changing to another.

Comment: mysql_num_rows returns a single number. What do you mean with "order mysq_num_rows"?

Comment: The previous query selects an amount of users, each user has it's own number of posts and that's where the mysql_num_rows comes in to place to count up the posts.. However I want to sort the posts from highest to lowest now. Is that possible by any chance?

Comment: As I told you before you can do it with PHP when you use sort functions or you can do it in MYSQL when you add order_by to your query. I don't know what is your table structure so I suppose that you can add ORDER_BY member_id to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right what you want to do actually you can do:

```
$fetchrank = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM leden WHERE level = 6 OR level = 106");

$totalposts = 0;
$getranks = mysql_fetch_array($fetchrank, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$getranks = rsort($getranks);
foreach ($getranks as $getrank) {

$getranked = mysql_query("SELECT nieuws_id FROM nieuws_berichten WHERE member_id='".$getrank['member_id']."'");
$critical = mysql_num_rows($getranked);
$posts = $critical;
$totalpostst = += $posts;
echo"".stripslashes(substr($getrank['gebruikersnaam'],0,25))." has ".$posts." posts!";
}
echo $totalposts;
echo"</div>";
```

to get the total amount of posts retrieved. To sort them you have to sort the array using asort or rsort (depending on the direction). See the [man page](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) for this. Sort is to be applied on the array. So I changed the code accordingly. Adapt

```
$getranks = rstort($getranks);
```

to your need based on the manual. You can see array content using

```
echo'<pre>';
print_r($getranks);
echo '</pre>';
```

to see what have changed inside the array.

Comment: Will I need to sort the variable $totalposts then instead so it can print it out through the rsort command? Or could you give an example?